# How do I search replace conditionally with awk or sed?

Tags: sed, awk

A file with this content:

```
var1 = true
```

How do I toggle this value with sed/awk?

I looked into groups, sed addresses..but nowhere does it say how to save a return value like "found it" or "not found it".
Search replace `var1 = true` to `var1 = false`

**edit**: doesn't seem to write into the file ..ever:

```
sed 's/var1 = true/var1 = foo/g' ./variables1
sed 's/var1 = false/var1 = true/g' ./variables1
sed 's/var1 = foo/var1 = false/g' ./variables1
```

command line output:

> var1 = foo
>
> var1 = true
>
> var1 = true

weird

**edit2**: it worked with sed -i for inplace editing

Comment: $? will return the success of the last command executed.  This will answer your "found it" or "not found it" request.  There are many sed/awk tutorials on stackoverflow and google for this question

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/var1 = true/var1 = false/g'
```

Comment: although that doesn't replace the value in the file, as he was asking.  write his shell script for him ;)

Comment: oh sorry, toggle.  Change true to foo, false to true, foo to false then using my sed expression above.

Comment: @Scott hm strange, it makes perfect sense but it still doesn't work. I'll edit my answer to what I have now.

Comment: Last one should be foo to false.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk` for the capturing parentheses:

```
printf "%s\n" "v1 = true" "v2=false" |
gawk '
    match($0, /([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*(true|false)/, ary) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", ary[1], ary[2] == "true" ? "false" : "true")
    }
'
```

Produces

```
v1 = false
v2 = true
```

To write to the same filename, use something like this:

```
filename=./variables1
tmpfile=$(mktemp)   # or use tmpfile="$filename.tmp.$(date +%s).$$"

gawk '...' "$filename" > "$tmpfile" && 
  mv "$filename" "$filename"~ && 
  mv "$tmpfile" "$filename"
```

Remove the first `mv` if you don't care to make a backup of the file.